# How do I convert .pvr (PVRTC) files to .png in iphone?

Tags: iphone, colors, png, transform

I need to convert some images from pvr to a png, in run-time in iphone.  I need to read them, decompress, transform some colors and then save then to pvr again or png. Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

This is apple [example program](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PVRTextureLoader/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows you how to load PVR texture files using the included PVRTexture class and then display them using OpenGL.

Comment: Yes, but in this example ends up with a glTexture2D and I need to save the resulting image as .png or .pvr file, not to draw it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically mean compressed PVRTC textures or *any* of the formats (e.g. 565, 1555) supported under the PVR? Also, what sort of transformations did you want to do to the colours?

The reason I ask is that, IIRC, there is code to read/manipulate PVR files on the [Imagination Technologies dev web pages](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-sdk.asp)  but if you want to change the colours of PVRTC compressed textures without actually recompressing the data entirely, there will be limits to what you can achieve. Certainly, changing the hue of regions etc will be possible, but manipulating individual pixels is likely to be too difficult.